# Excel VBA code for searching PDF in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, acrobat

I want to search a PDF file for a string and print the number of counted instances. I've done this for Word, Excel, and Powerpoint, but never Acrobat. There is an error when I call acroDoc.Range, so I assume this is the wrong syntax for Acrobat.

> Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

I can't find answers in Adobe's documentation. What is the correct syntax for selecting the whole document and searching for a string?

```
Sub pdfSearch()

Dim acroApp As Object
Dim acroDoc As Object
Dim aRng As Object
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set acroDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.pddoc")
acroDoc.Open ("C:\Documents\example.pdf")
Set aRng = acroDoc.Range
With aRng.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="desk", MatchCase:=False)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
acroDoc.Close 0
Set aRng = Nothing
Set acroDoc = Nothing
Set acroApp = Nothing
Debug.Print (i)

End Sub
```

Comment: "an error", what is it?

Comment: @Masoud Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat doesn't have a concept of Range. FindText finds the specified text, scrolls so that it is visible, and highlights it. The return value is -1 when the text is found. Unless you also pass a parameter to reset the selection, subsequent calls will start where you left off so to get the count, you just loop until the return value is something other than -1. I haven't used VAB in quite a while but I think the code would look like this...

```
i = 0
Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set acroDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
acroDoc.Open ("C:\Documents\example.pdf")
Do While acroDoc.FindText("desk",0) == -1
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Documentation to FindText:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_API_OLE_Objects%2FFindText.htm

Comment: It stops on the acroDoc.Open line. It's giving me a Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Your code matches the SDK documentation so I'm not sure what is messing things up.

Comment: Should there be a space after Open and the paren? That's probably my typo.

Comment: Yes there should be a space. VBA autocorrects the code to include a space.

Comment: acroDoc.Open ("C:\Documents\example.pdf","") should do it.

Comment: No luck. acroDoc.Open ("C:\Documents\example.pdf","")  returns a syntax error